# Drag google chrome window from maximized state?

Tags: google-chrome, windows-10

I used to be able to grab the chrome window and drag it. What this would do is, it would make chrome go from maximized to smaller window state and I was able to place it where I wanted.
Recently (after a fresh install), when chrome window is maximized, it unfortunately does not budge any more when I try to drag it. (I can only drag chrome window when it is not maximized.)

Is this due to a new version of chrome, and this is how it's going to be now? Or maybe my new installation does not have a certain setting set up? Is there any way I could make chrome window draggable when it is maximized?

Comment: This is not a question about a Web Application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, the issue was not with google chrome, but actually with my Windows 10 setup. In

> Settings -> System -> Multitasking

one has to set "Snap windows" to "On". This makes all windows draggable from a maximized state.